# Add aspnet_users UserName value into my own table

Tags: asp.net

I would like to insert UserName from aspnet_users into my own table called Members. My sqldatasource looks like as follows. At the end in the InsertParameters I have added ProfileParameter but its not working. Just to get the values going, I have hardcoded 'testhere' value in the insertcommand. My SQLDatasource looks as follows.

Please help !!!

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    OnInserted= "on_inserted"
    OnUpdated = "on_updated"

        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:test1ConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [member] WHERE [id] = @id" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [member] ([firstname], [lastname],[username]) VALUES (@firstname, @lastname,'testhere');
                            set @id = @@identity"  
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [member] WHERE ([id] = @id)" 

        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [member] SET [firstname] = @firstname, [lastname] = @lastname WHERE [id] = @id" 
        onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="firstname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type=Int32 Direction=Output />
            <asp:Parameter Name="firstname" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
            <asp:ProfileParameter Name="username" Type=String /> 
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I am disappointed that no one attempted to answer this one.

Comment: I'll be glad to help you. What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you going to have some kind of UI to capture the user accounts before saving to your [member] table?

Comment: Jose, thanks for responding. I am trying to create UI for insert/update. I am trying to dynamically programmatically populate controls instead of adding them in aspx page. That is the challenge. I can not find good information on this topic when I google for it. I appreciate your help. How can I contact you directly when I post a question here???

Comment: Jose, I dont know if you could see this comment but I reiterated my question again at SO with no response...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863772/keep-getting-extra-added-in-details-view

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. as a simple one:

- Try changing the InsertParameter (username) to be an asp:Parameter.
- Add a asp:HiddenField control with ID of username
- onpageload, set the value of the username hiddenfield to be Page.User.Identity.Name

Magic!